# Popup image over text in homepage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this issue and I don't know how to solve it...

When entering in my homepage, I want to popup a picture so as the visitors could see directly a new event before they enter the website. I tried it with JavaScript but I didn't make it to work.

I don't want to make a new homepage, but I want this picture to pop up over the normal homepage and when clicking the picture it will redirect you to the competition, otherwise by clicking anywhere else it will make the picture go away.

I know how to add the links but I am stacked in the JavaScript part.

If you could help me on how to pop up the picture when someone visit my website I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What code do you have currently? It is more a matter of CSS to create this and use JS to show it.

Comment: have you tried using any jquery library?

Comment: you can look at this http://visuallightbox.com/rq/automatically-open-the-lightbox-popup-upon-opening-the-page-r.html

Answer (score 1):

Create a div which contains your pop'in and use jQuery when the page load :

```
<div id="mypopup">
     **** Somes stuff here ****
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#mypopup").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have an image with `position: absolute` property. And place it wherever you want on screen (show it default)

Use jQuery library, to do the below stuff to hide it.

```
$('.image-class').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('body').click(function(e){
    $('.image-class').hide();
});
```